# Disk Event-ID 32 in server with Hyper-V virtual machine

Tags: virtualization, windows-10, windows

We have a server running on Windows Server 2012 R2 and it hosts a Hyper-v virtual machine (configuration: Windows 10, version 20H2, min 16GB & max 32GB RAM with 4 processor cores) . We notice in the event logs of the server: Event-id 32
"The driver detected that the device \Device\Harddiskx\DR**x** has its write cache enabled.  Data corruption may occur."

1. We would like to know why is this warning coming in Event logs?
2. We have tried to disable the write cache, but it is not letting us disable and giving the error
   "Windows could not change the write-caching setting for the device. Your device might not support this feature or changing the setting"

As per the document from Microsoft the setting cannot be disabled: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v-storage-caching-layers-data-consistency-requirements

We found no issues with the hard disk, and latest firmware updates are installed.
Please suggest a solution to prevent the disk warnings.